# Nuxt: asyncData and Fetch don't run on browser reload

Tags: nuxt.js

When reloading the browser asyncData and Fetch only runs backend, not in the browser.

To eliminate other problems I set up a blank Nuxt installation with the following settings:

**Project name** testproject
**Project description** My luminous Nuxt.js project
**Use a custom server framework** none
**Choose features to install** Linter / Formatter, Prettier
**Use a custom UI framework** none
**Use a custom test framework** none
**Choose rendering mode** Universal
**Choose a package manager** npm

I replaced the entire `pages/index.vue` with:

```html
<template>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData: function() {
    console.log('async data')
  },
  fetch: function() {
    console.log('fetch')
  }
}
</script>
```

To allow console log I change `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  }
```

It works on the first load, and navigation but not on browser reload (user-initiated command-R, or reload button click). Tested in latest chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Working totally fine on my side @jakub-záruba.
Maybe try to setup the project with `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`. This will take the latest version as of today (`v3.4.0`). Maybe you do have an old CLI ?

Here is my project's settings written in text as asked in the comments (even if it can totally be found out in the Github repo)

```
Programming language: JS
Package manager: yarn
UI framework: none
Nuxt modules: none
Linting tools: ESlint + Prettier
Testing Framework: none
Rendering mode: Universal
Deployment target: Server
Development tools: None
Continuous integration: None
Version control system: Git
```

And here is my code

```html
<template>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  fetch() {
    console.log('fetch 33')
  },
  asyncData() {
    console.log('async data 33')
  },
}
</script>
```

Working perfectly fine !
[image]

I've hosted [my code on Github](https://github.com/kissu/so-install-test), if you want to maybe download it and inspect that it's not working on your side, we could maybe debug it better.

Comment: I don't really see the issue here because in the docs: [answer], it does not state anything related. I told that it's working great, with the CLI and it's version. The screenshots are additional context to my github repo, to allow for a faster view of the fact that it's working. I know that Imgur may one day die, or maybe even remove my images. But my code will still be there and available for him to check. If Github dies, I guess that I can still send a `.zip` but ehh, I will not dump all my files here just because one platform may one day die since it will be totally unreadable.